# Why the objects are moving down direction and not up?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It seems like down or the direction is moving backward instead to move forward.
I tried to make - 50 instead + 50

```
objectstoMove[i].transform.position.x - 50
```

I also tried to add minus in the start:

```
-objectstoMove[i].transform.position.x + 50
```

But nothing worked so far. The objects are moving slow and smooth but I can't control the direction.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3f;

    private GameObject[] objectstoMove;

    // Use this for initialization
    public void Init()
    {
        objectstoMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Objecttomove");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (objectstoMove != null)
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            for (int i = 0; i < objectstoMove.Length; i++)
            {
                objectstoMove[i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objectstoMove[i].transform.position, new Vector3(0, objectstoMove[i].transform.position.x + 50, 0), step);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share some more information about what you are making? Else if not, the movement you do is only on the X-axis, you will have to manipulate the y value aswell for 2D environments and the z value aswell in 3D evironments.

Comment: Why are you writing the `objectstoMove[i].transform.position.x` on the `Y` position?   => _`"new Vector3(0, objectstoMove[i].transform.position.x + 50, 0)"`_

Answer (score 3):

You put the `x` value in the `y` value of `Vector3(x,y,z)`

```
new Vector3(0, objectstoMove[i].transform.position.x + 50, 0), step);
```

It has to be

```
new Vector3(objectstoMove[i].transform.position.x + 50, 0, 0), step);
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
new Vector3(0, objectstoMove[i].transform.position.x + 50, 0)
```

creates a new vector with only the ***Y*** component assigned. If you want your object to move right, for example, you should do it like this:

```
myObject.position = myObject.position + Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```